# Implement hide()/show() instead of using backStack with Android Fratments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So, I'm still new on Android Fragments, but if I got it correctly, when you remove a Fragment and stack it to the back stack with addBackStack (according to [Android Developer's Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png)) you get this portion of view destroyed and when it pops up to the screen again it has to reload all it's components.

I'm specially concerned with that because one of my fragments contains a map, which is a lot of data to reload (specially if using 3G).

In that case, is it a better practice to implement hide and show to all my fragments when manipulating them? 
I just see a little problem there because I'd have to create my own stack to know the order they were called and have to be shown again.

Well, it's now a huge problem, but I wanted to hear from someone if it is worth putting effort on it to implement this approach instead of the existing back stack.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I said "remove a Fragment" I meant calling the replace() method

Comment: Check if that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924725/fragmenttransaction-add-behavior

Comment: when you replacing fragment the old one just stay inactive , you must set your large loading in onCreate and it will load only once

Comment: The hide/show solution is the most lightweight because Android doesn't have to reload its components. The drawback of this is the memory usage! If you have many fragments that hold a lot of stuff into your memory you can get OutOfMemory exception

Comment: I still didn't get an answer for what I asked. I mean, I just want my fragments to hide/show instead of adding to back stack because I don't want them to reload (does it make sense?). However, this approach requires me to hard code a interface or a superclass to handle the stack of fragments and hide/show the others.

Comment: @IspasClaudiu, can you add a reference to that or have you experienced this problem? I don't have many fragments in my case.

Comment: You can use show/hide for your fragments. It is safe and faster than atach/detach! If you don't have many fragments than it should work smoothly without problems. I've experienced OutOfMemory exception when I used a lot of fragments that were holding large bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ´attach´ and ´detach´ operations are another way around to your problem. The fragment instances will still exist, but deactivated and not visible, and you can recover them using the FragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

If one of your fragments contain google map, it's better to use show/hide operations with the fragment views in order to avoid google map black flickering bug. Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25206078/2999943